# Cannot connect to MySQL within running docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, containers

we have a scenario where we launch a MySQL docker container, try to connect to the MySQL within the container, and do something, after that we stop and remove the container. We do this for hundreds of times, say 200 and more in our code. Occasionally, we failed to connect to the MySQL within docker container, and we don't know why. Does anybody has similar experience or any guidance on this? Our code seems like the following pseudo lines:

```
   for (int count = 0; count < 200; count++) {
           //launch docker container
           MySQLContainer container = MySQLContainer.newInstance();
           container.start();

           //initialize DB manager and try to get a connection
           DbManager.initConnectionPool(container.getMySQLAddressInfo());
           Connection conn = DbManager.getConnection();

           //do something with the conn
           DoSomething(conn);

           //destroy container
           container.destroy(); //the same as 'docker stop XXX; docker rm XXX'
   }
```

DbManager.getConnection failed occasionally here. What the DbManager does is to create a new BasicDatasource and use this datasource to initialize a collection pool for applications. We use JDBC MySQL connector as the underlying driver. It's very weird. Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried connecting to the MySQL Container normally from terminal with the details of `container.getMySQLAddressInfo()`?

Comment: I am trying to do that, and it will take hours. Before there are any results, I am here to looking for tips from those who many have encountered it before. Thanks.

Comment: @Gangaraju, when this occurred, I tried to connect to the MySQL within the docker container, and I could do that. Very strange.

Comment: @Gangaraju，but sometimes when I tried to ran MySQL command line, I got the following errors: ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 2

Comment: Might it be because the MySQL daemon in the container hasn't started up fully (i.e. still not accepting connections, or not in a state where connections can be processed) although the container has already been started? I had this situation where I had to do a busy wait on the port for the daemon to properly start...

Comment: @Gangaraju, yeah, I think it's a bug of docker daemon; if you start and stop such kind of containers for hundreds of times, docker daemon won't work as expected. Might be resource lock or leak. No idea.